# zk pages not correctly visualized in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, zk

Good morning, everyone,
my colleague uses the same Eclipse that I do, the 2019-12 with Java 1.8 and we both have ZKStudios installed as plugins. I see everything correctly zuls with all the tags, while she sees a text page. It completely lacks the option to see the zuls.
She has reinstalled ZkStudios several times but to no avail.
I attach screens of what I see and what my colleague sees.
Has anyone ever had a similar problem?

My zk pages correct
[image: My zk pages correct]

My project config
[image: My project config]

my coworker zul page, not correct
[image: my coworker zul page, not correct]

my coworker config
[image: my coworker config]

We tried to reinstall the plugin

New info, thanks to comments, My coworker has this error when  she tries to install zk studios :

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.zkoss.eclipse.editor [731]
Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.wst.common.snippets
-> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.wst.common.snippets; bundle-version="1.2.500.v201811170421"; singleton:="true"
org.eclipse.wst.common.snippets [428]
Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.gef; bundle-version="[3.10.0,6.0.0)"
-> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.gef; bundle-version="3.13.0.202211301913"; singleton:="true"
org.eclipse.gef [498]
Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.draw2d; bundle-version="[3.7.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
-> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.draw2d; bundle-version="3.12.0.202211301913"
org.eclipse.draw2d [490]
Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.zkoss.eclipse.zks
-> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.zkoss.eclipse.zks; bundle-version="2.0.5.v202202111348"; singleton:="true"
org.zkoss.eclipse.zks [735]
Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.gef
-> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.gef; bundle-version="3.13.0.202211301913"; singleton:="true"
Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.gef
-> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.gef; bundle-version="3.13.0.202211301913"; singleton:="true"

Comment: Actually filling in the image descriptions would make it far easier to understand which ones represent success or failure. Are these files supposed to be opened in a specific editor?

Comment: The files are supposed to open in zul editor, a plugins from ZKStudios

Comment: Is that the editor your coworker is using? Check the file's Open With menu, as well as the Content Types and File Associations preference pages.

Comment: according to the error, it looks like zk studio is not installed successfully for missing some required bundled `org.eclipse.gef`. But this bundle should exist in eclipse. I cannot tell the reason. Maybe try a different version of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, you don't open a zul file with a zul editor: (check the icon)
[image: check the icon]

The zul editor icon is:
[image]

You can open a zul with zul editor:
[image]

Check file type and editor association:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Yes the problem is that my coworker doesn't have the option of ZUL editor.  My coworker in Project Facets has this "org.zkoss.eclipse.project.zksupports 1.0.2" without the icon of ZK Studios that I have. We tried to reinstall the plugin but nothing change.

Comment: Is the zk studio installed successfully? check eclipse log to see if there is any related error.

Comment: eclipse log is at `[eclipse workspace location]\.metadata\.log`

Comment: Hi Hawk, I put the error in the first page